# Jquery MultiZoom Plugin Not Working Properly

Tags: jquery, image, zooming

I am trying to zoom image.
I have loaded 4 images.
In one main div I have taken 1 large image.
Upon it I have taken thumb images.
When I am clicking on thumb Image, Image opens separately like following :
[image]

I want to open Image in main Image div :

[image]

Why Image Opens like that on click I don't know.
I want to open Image in main div of large image.

Code Main Image :

```
    <div id="productmainimage" class="targetarea">
<a href="#"> 
<img id="mainimg" name="mainimg" alt="No Image Available" src="http://localhost:8080/B2B_Solution/product_images/Tulips1760331818.jpg" height="330px" width="290px" style="border-top-left-radius: 3px; border-top-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px; border-bottom-left-radius: 3px; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; width: 290px; height: 330px;"> 
</a>
    </div>
```

Thumb Image Div :

```
<div id="mainimg thumbs" style="margin-left: 25px;">
<a href="product_images/Tulips1760331818.jpg" data-dims="290, 330">
<img src="product_images/Tulips1760331818.jpg" height="45" width="55">
</a>
<a href="product_images/MvcCaptchaGoogle1450547827.jpg" data-dims="290, 330" data-large="product_images/MvcCaptchaGoogle1450547827.jpg" data-title="L32840">
<img src="product_images/MvcCaptchaGoogle1450547827.jpg" height="45" width="55">
</a>
<a href="product_images/nokia-lumia-800n1558615039.jpg" data-dims="290, 330" data-large="product_images/nokia-lumia-800n1558615039.jpg" data-title="L32840">
<img src="product_images/nokia-lumia-800n1558615039.jpg" height="45" width="55">
</a>
<a href="product_images/lumia-music866211759.jpg" data-dims="290, 330" data-large="product_images/lumia-music866211759.jpg" data-title="L32840">
<img src="product_images/lumia-music866211759.jpg" height="45" width="55">
</a>            
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

                $('#mainimg').addimagezoom({ // single image zoom
                    zoomrange: [1, 2],
                    magnifiersize: [290,330],
                    magnifierpos: 'right',
                    cursorshade: true,
                });             
            })
```

I have used [multizoom.js](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/multizoom.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">


jQuery(document).ready(function($){


$('#image1').addimagezoom({ // single image zoom
    zoomrange: [3, 10],
    magnifiersize: [300,300],
    magnifierpos: 'right',
    cursorshade: true,
    largeimage: 'hayden.jpg'
})

})



</script>
```

more options are as follows

```
descArea: '#description', // description selector (optional - but required if descriptions are used)
descpos: true, // if set to true - description position follows image position at a set 

distance, defaults to false (optional)

imagevertcenter: true, // zoomable image centers vertically in its container (optional)

magvertcenter: true, // magnified area centers vertically in relation to the zoomable image (optional)

zoomrange: [3, 10],
magnifiersize: [250,250],
magnifierpos: 'right',
cursorshadecolor: '#fdffd5',
cursorshade: true,
disablewheel: true
```

Comment: -I Have used that one also but it's not working. When I click on image image change but when I hover on main image it zooms original first image. I think problem is in any `<div>` or `<a>` or in `<img>`

Comment: I want to change value of `largezoom:` on thumb image click but I don't know how to do that.. Any suggestion ??

Comment: just try to check http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/ till i will try to change at my side

Comment: I have that code but I want to display thumb images below main image and when I click on thumb image, it should change main image also zoom thumb one properly but it's not working.

Comment: go to this link .. this is as per your requirement with download http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom

Comment: Yes I have downloaded that example but if it is possible then please help me to solve this one because in example that I have downloaded which told me in that also no thumb image given on html page, it's given in folder but nor the code for to change image and zoom it. it only show  one image and zoom it.